# How to set focus on dropdown by its name -javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a no of dropdown list as follows

```
<select name="dropname[0]">....</select>
<select name="dropname[1]">....</select>
<select name="dropname[2]">....</select>
<select name="dropname[3]">....</select>....
```

Now I want to set focus on second drop down list.I tried these

```
document.getElementsByName('dropname')[1].focus();
```

results this error

```
TypeError: document.getElementsByName(...)[1] is undefined
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with jQuery, try something like

```
$('select[name^="dropname"]').eq(1).focus();

// $('select[name^="dropname"]') < elements whos name starts with "dropname"
// .eq(1) < select one based on its index
// .focus(); < use jQuery's focus method to set the focus
```

Comment: @manuthalasseril No problem! Please note that the names are actually `dropname[0]`, `dropname[1]` etc. Perhaps a common class could be more suitable for this scenario.

Comment: Actually these dropdowns are processed under one array in server.so its names like that..

Answer (score 6):

Try using jquery focus like

```
$("#id2").focus();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
var i = 0 //or 1,2,3

document.getElementsByName('dropname['+i+']')[0].focus();
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="1">
    <option>1</option>
</select>
<select name="2">
    <option>2</option>
</select>
<select name="3">
    <option>3</option>
</select>
<select name="4">
    <option>4</option>
</select>
<select name="5">
    <option>5</option>
</select>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 i=2;
 $('select[name="'+i+'"]').focus();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

hope this will help you.!

Answer (score 0):

Most easiest way to focus on element properly with click is

```
$('#nights').show().focus().click();
```